# Does $\omega \wedge \mathrm{d} \omega=0$ (where $\omega$ is a non-vanishing $1$-form) imply $\mathrm{d} \omega \in \langle \omega\rangle$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\omega$ be a *non-vanishing* (for clarification: nowhere vanishing) smooth $1$-form on a smooth manifold $M$, if $\mathrm{d}\omega \wedge \omega =0$, do we already have $\mathrm{d}\omega= \sum a_i \wedge \omega$ for some $1$-forms $a_i$?

Comment: Hint: Extend $\omega$ to a basis for the $1$-forms.

Comment: @Ted Could you please post a solution : I don't understand what you suggest.

Comment: I think I understand the hint (we would have for $d\omega= \sum a_j \omega_j \wedge \omega_k$ that $\omega \wedge d\omega= 0$ implies (by linear indepence) that all the  $\omega \wedge \omega_j \wedge \omega_k$ must vanish). But, being a beginner in differential forms on smooth manifolds: can we extend to a basis globally? Or does this suffices locally?

Comment: Dear @user110071 when you talk of basis, you must indicate of what vector space. If you consider the space of global differential $1$-forms $\Omega^1(M)$ you can choose a basis $(\omega)_i$ of it (with some $\omega_{i_0}=\omega$) but the subtle point is that the products $\omega_i\wedge \omega_j$ will definitely not be a basis of $\Omega^2(M)$ and you can't write $d\omega$ the way you do in your comment. That's why I believe that Ted's hint won't work.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg As I understand it, one wants that $\{\omega_i(p)\}$ is a basis of $T_pM^\ast$ for every $p$. Then $\omega_1 \wedge \omega_j$ is a basis of $\Omega^2(M)$ as a $C^\infty(M)$-module, isn't it?

Comment: Dear @Daniel: exactly, but as you very judiciously  point out in your answer it is impossible to find such a basis of $\Gamma(M,\Lambda ^2T^*M)=\Omega^2 (M)$ unless $M$ is a parallelizable manifold, a very rare occurrence  even among spheres, as you well know !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes. That's where the second part of my answer helps, however.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg With a local frame on a coordinate patch $U$, $d\omega \wedge \omega = 0$ gives you smooth forms $a_i^U,\, 2\leqslant i \leqslant \dim M$ such that $d\omega = \sum a_i^U\wedge \omega$. Then take a partition of unity to glue $\{ a_i^U : U \in \mathscr{U}\}$ together.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg If I have $d\omega\lvert_U = \alpha^U\wedge \omega$, and take a partition of unity $\{\varphi^U : U \in \mathscr{U}\}$, then $$d\omega = \sum_U \varphi^U d\omega = \sum_U \varphi^U (\alpha^U\wedge \omega) = \left(\sum_U \varphi^U \alpha^U\right)\wedge\omega.$$

Comment: @Daniel. Yes, I agree, this is correct: why not post it as an answer in which you would also explain how to solve the local case on $U$, explaining how the non-vanishing hypothesis is used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, being a beginner in differential forms on smooth manifolds: can we extend to a basis globally?

In general, no. On [parallelizable manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold), you can extend to a global basis in the sense that $(\omega(p),\omega_2(p),\dotsc,\omega_k(p))$ are a basis of the cotangent space at every point, but not on other manifolds.

> Or does this suffices locally?

If your definition of manifold includes paracompactness (or second countability, which implies paracompactness for locally Euclidean Hausdorff spaces), then there exist smooth partitions of unity subordinate to every open cover of $M$.

You can then extend $\omega$ to a local frame on every coordinate patch $U$
 - meaning you find smooth $1$-forms $\omega_2,\dotsc,\omega_n$ on $U$ such that $\omega(p),\omega_2(p),\dotsc, \omega_n(p)$ is a basis of $T_p^\ast M$ for all $p\in U$ - and the condition $d\omega \wedge \omega = 0$ then implies that, with smooth functions $\beta_k$, we have

$$d\omega = \underbrace{\sum_{k = 2}^n \beta_k\cdot \omega_k}_{\alpha_U}\wedge \omega$$

on $U$. Cover $M$ with a family $\mathfrak{U}$ of such coordinate patches and find a subordinate smooth partition of unity $\{ \varphi_U : U \in \mathfrak{U}\}$. Then you have

$$d\omega = \sum_U \varphi_U\cdot d\omega = \sum_U \varphi_U (\alpha_U\wedge \omega) = \Biggl(\sum_U \varphi_U\cdot \alpha_U\Biggr)\wedge \omega.$$

Comment: +1 for drawing attention to the importance   for global forms $\omega_i\in \Omega^1(M)$ of having as values at a point $p\in M$ linearly  independent linear forms $\omega_i(p)\in T_p ^*(M)$

Answer (score 2):

No: $M=\mathbb R^2,\: \omega=xd y$

**Edit**
In the first version of the question "non vanishing" was in brackets and I interpreted the question as "not identically zero but maybe having zeros", as is indeed the case in my example..

Comment: This form is not nonvanishing.

Comment: Then $d\omega = (dx/x) \wedge \omega$.

Comment: Then $\mathrm{d}\omega = \mathrm{d}x \wedge \mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x \wedge (x \mathrm{d}y)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I had the "non-vanishing" in brackets only at first, so now I see that for the statement to have a chance to hold (I still do not know if it is true), this is at least necessary.